# How to read data with ApacheSpark,path to directory?

Tags: apache-spark

This is pwd of my spark-shell

```
/home/milenko/spark-2.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7/bin
```

and this is pwd of folder where my data is located

```
/home/milenko/dom1/wikipedia/src/main/scala/wikipedia
```

If I try from my spark-shell

```
scala> val wikiRdd = sc.parallelize(/home/milenko/dom1/wikipedia/src/main/scala/wikipedia/WikipediaARticle)
<console>:25: error: not found: value /
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
       val wikiRdd = sc.parallelize(/home/milenko/dom1/wikipedia/src/main/scala/wikipedia/WikipediaARticle)
                                    ^
<console>:25: error: not found: value /
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.
       val wikiRdd = sc.parallelize(/home/milenko/dom1/wikipedia/src/main/scala/wikipedia/WikipediaARticle)
```

How to set proper path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to read a file. Enclose path in double quotes "

```
val input = sc.textFile("/tmp/filename")
```